# Regex to match functions and function calls, but excluding JavaScript keywords

Tags: javascript, regex, vim

I have a VIM buffer containing the following pieces of code:

```
function foo () {...}
foo ();
foo();
if (foo ()) {...}
function bar() {...}
bar = function () {...}
for (...) {}
bar (foo());
```

I want only match the function declarations and function calls (that means that JavaScript statements and keywords will be excluded. e.g. `if`, `for`, `switch` etc) that contain a space between the last letter and opening bracket, **but** excepting `function () {...}` case.

So, the matched parts in the example above will be:

```
function foo () {...}
foo ();
if (foo ()) {...}
bar (foo());
```

I tried to do:

```
/[a-z] (
```

This matches all cases where the space preceds the opening bracket.

What's the regular expression that matches these cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This substitution works on your sample:

```
:%s/\(if\|for\|while\)\@<!\zs\s\+\ze(//g
```

More info:

```
:help \@<!
:help \zs
:help \ze
```